# «Отчего так в России берёзы шумят?» Особенности пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, и, поэзия

Есть несколько вариантов оформления слов песни (автор — М. Андреев).

[**I.**](https://www.gl5.ru/lube-berezy.html)
А на сердце опять горячо, горячо **и** опять, и опять без ответа.
А листочек с березки упал на плечо, **он, как я,** оторвался от веток.

[**II.**](https://lyricstranslate.com/ru/berezy-berezy-birches.html-0)
А на сердце опять горячо-горячо,
**И** опять, и опять без ответа.
А листочек с берёзки упал на плечо,
**Он как я,** оторвался от веток.

[**III.**](http://www.sentido.ru/songs.php?id_song=2879)
А на сердце опять горячо, горячо,
**И** опять, и опять без ответа.
А листочек с березки упал на плечо,
**Он как я** оторвался от веток.

Поделитесь своими знаниями и своим ви́дением.
1. Нужна ли запятая перед **и** (после второго слова "горячо" или "горячо-горячо")?
2. Какова правильная пунктуация в выделенном месте?

Comment: Вообще-то лист отрывается от одной ветки (это по поводу *оторвался от веток").

Comment: Да, конечно, отрывается от ветки. И, конечно, вопрос о "горячо" предполагался (Вы его успешно увидели и задали). Но **"столько много всего"** невозможно объять в одном вопросе! [Я уже говорила однажды, что Вы — _замечательный_ читатель. Повторяю это ещё раз.]

Answer (score 4):

1) ***А на сердце опять горячо, горячо, //и опять, и опять без ответа.***

Можно рассматривать ***и опять, и опять без ответа*** как присоединительную конструкцию. Пауза явно присутствует, ее надо обозначить запятой.

**Примечание.**

Я думаю,что **вариант без запятой некорректен:** А на сердце опять горячо, горячо и опять, и опять без ответа.

Нельзя соединить союзом И в одну фразу  две пары однородных членов, которые имеют собственные знаки препинания.

2) ***Он, как я, //оторвался от веток.***

Классический сравнительный оборот, обособляется запятыми.

Интересно то, что в устной речи **пауза делается только после оборота**, но это связано скорее с тем, что интонационно выделить оборот паузами с двух сторон в таком предложении (и тем более в песне) сложно.

Поэтому здесь действует **грамматический принцип** постановки запятых.

Answer (score 1):

> А на сердце опять горячо(,) горячо

Запятая или дефис после первого "горячо"? Ответ: запятая. См. ответы на мой вопрос [Запятая или дефис при лексическом повторе?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447378/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5)

> А на сердце опять горячо, горячо(,) и опять, и опять без ответа.

Ставить ли запятую перед *и*? Ответ: я бы поставил. Давайте разберемся. Что хотел сказать автор?

Вариант 1. На сердце горячо и безответно. Тогда без запятой:
*А на сердце опять горячо, горячо и опять, и опять без ответа.*

Вариант 2. На сердце горячо, и нет ответа (на заданные выше вопросы: отчего так в России березы шумят и т. д.) Тогда с запятой:
*А на сердце опять горячо, горячо, и опять, и опять без ответа.*
А еще лучше с точкой и многоточием :
*А на сердце опять горячо, горячо. И опять, и опять без ответа...*

Другими словами, пунктуация зависит от того, хотел автор понять происходящее сердцем (вариант 1) или головой (вариант 2) . И хотя поэтический, сердечный подход (вариант 1) больше соответствует духу стихотворения, я бы голосовал за второй вариант, более корректный грамматически (учитывая некоторую грамматическую корявость выражения "на сердце без ответа").

> Он(,) как я(,) оторвался от веток.

Обособлять ли оборот "как я"? Ответ: обособлять.

Тут у меня нет сомнений. Автор сравнивает себя с листком не тотально, так сказать, а только в своей оторванности от веток (он, так же как и я, оторвался от веток). Имеем сравнительный оборот и выделяем его запятыми:

**Он, как я, оторвался от веток.**

Сравните: *Он как я, оторвался от веток* означает *Он подобен мне, (так же) оторвался от веток.* Уподобление и бессоюзное сложное предложение.

Вариант без запятых считаю некорректным.

Comment: "Горячо, горячо" и "горячо-горячо" читаются по-разному. Это или перечисление, или произношение сложного слова, то есть практически без паузы и с основным ударением на втором слове. В песне, я думаю, первый вариант (с двумя ударениями). Я даже песню послушала.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Нужна ли запятая перед и (после второго слова "горячо" или "горячо-горячо")?

Запятая факультативна. Тут, думаю, дело в том, что текст грамматически небезупречен, трудно даже наверняка сказать, чем в предложении является присоединяемая часть. Как самостоятельное предложение оно незаконченно, а если смотреть на фразу как на единое целое, то получается не слишком осмысленное без контекста "а на сердце... опять без ответа". Впрочем, уже давно подмечено, что искать смысл в текстах современных песен - занятие неблагодарное.

Впрочем, в данном случае **доводов в пользу запятой неизмеримо больше**.
Запятая может отсутствовать тогда и только тогда, когда фраза понимается как ***"А на сердце горячо и без ответа"***, уточняемое с помощью второстепенных членов и их повторов. В этом и только в этом случае **И** является союзом, соединяющим однородные члены и таким образом "съедающим" запятую. Вы верите, что семантическая структура фразы именно такая? Я - нет.

Любая же другая интерпретация грамматики приводит к необходимости поставить запятую.

> Какова правильная пунктуация в выделенном месте?

Здесь классический сравнительный оборот, иное было бы слишком фантастической трактовкой (образ действия, фразеологизм - и проч. здесь просто невозможно себе представить). А потому обособление. И это независимо от интонации/пауз.

Но вся заморочка проистекает опять-таки из-за неряшливости авторского текста.
Это же ведь не лист, словно лирический герой, оторвался от веток, а наоборот: герой уподобляет себя листу. 
Напиши автор эту фразу с телегой позади лошади: ***Я, как (и) лист, оторвался от веток***, сомнений бы не было никаких.

Comment: *Вы верите, что семантическая структура фразы именно такая? Я - нет.* === О семантике я уже писал.  Если автор хотел понять происходящее сердцем, то слова  "на сердце без ответа" верно выражают семантику.  А верите ли Вы, что грамматическая структура может быть такой: ""А на сердце горячо и без ответа"?

Comment: @М_Г признаюсь, в данном случае я не принимал во внимание другие ответы. Но семантика в моем понимании тут вообще никак не связана с тем, каким местом лирический герой все это воспринимает. Я о другом, о семантике предопределяемой синтаксисом. То есть именно о том, что вы, судя по всему вложили здесь в понятие "грамматическая структура". То есть по сути именно на этот ваш вопрос я и дал ответ "не верю". Это начисто лишает фразу смысла. Впрочем, уже сказал, я смысла в современных песенных текстах давно уже не ищу. .